# How to split a table in two tables

Tags: python, split

I ran across the following problem. I have a database called oscars and i am asked to to the following:

We may assume that there is exactly one Oscar ceremony per year. With this in mind, how could you split the Oscars table in two tables that would hold the same information, but in a more efficient way? Save the columns of your proposed two tables as two Series variables w4_table1, w4_table2.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a *[mcve]*. This will help use understand your question better and provide an appropriate response.

Comment: This question lacks detail, especially what the actual table you're supposed to split looks like.

Comment: Can you please clarify what kind of tables? A SQL database table? A python table coming from a module (e.g. pandas)? A self written table class?

Comment: It is a database sql table. I loaded it this way:conn = sqlite3.connect('ga2-oscars.csv')

movie_data = pd.read_csv(csv_file, na_values=[''], keep_default_na=False)                                                        
 movies.db = movie_data.to_sql('oscars', conn, if_exists= 'append', index= False)